# Matrix stacking with column name in R

Tags: r

I found many threads related to matrix stacking with column name but there is no information which help in this problem.
I have a matrix like this

> ```
>    Lcover   
> County        8         9   
>   53009 868.935 1171.0050  
>   53055      NA  414.9733  
>   53057      NA  276.5450   
>   53073 706.700        NA
> ```

and I am trying to create a dataframe like this

```
County Lcover Value  
53009   8     868.935  
53009   9    1171.0050   
53055   9     414.9733  
53057   9     276.5450  
53073   8     706.700
```

Would anyone suggest me, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Deven

Comment: Have a look at function `melt()` in package `reshape2`.

Comment: That looks more like how an R "table" would be printed. What do you get with as.data.frame(), ... since there is a table-method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andrie noted, `melt()` function makes this trivially easy:

```
x <- read.table(text = "County        8         9   
  53009 868.935 1171.0050  
  53055      NA  414.9733  
  53057      NA  276.5450   
  53073 706.700        NA ", header = TRUE)

require(reshape2)
melt(x, id.vars = "County", na.rm=TRUE)

  County variable     value
1  53009       X8  868.9350
4  53073       X8  706.7000
5  53009       X9 1171.0050
6  53055       X9  414.9733
7  53057       X9  276.5450
```

The "X" appears in front of your columns because R tries to make valid column names with the `make.names()` function. You can disable that functionality with `check.names = FALSE` when reading in / creating your table. Or just drop the X from the resulting column with `gsub("X","", variable)`.If you want to retain the NA values in the melted data.frame, change `na.rm = FALSE` in the `melt()` function.

Comment: Andrie: Thank you. But melt() function could not found even after installing reshape2 library. Plus, the input, which is given here is a part of a large file. So, can the file be read using read.delim() or read.table()?

Comment: @user1252544 - did you load the reshape2 package with the `library(reshape2)` command? After installing, you still need to load it for your session. As for `read.table()` or `read.delim()`, navigate to the directory where your file is stored with `setwd()`. You can check your current directory with `getwd()`. Once in the appropriate directory (think navigating through the Windows Explorer tab), then call your read.xxx function with the `file` parameter set to the name of your file. Have you perused the intro to R? http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html. Can be very helpful!

Comment: Chase: thank you very much, I have used R before but for simple task, like plotting graphs. Anyway, you are very helpful. I installed the reshape2 this afternoon but forgot to load it, which I did now. I also used read.delim() function to read file and followed your instruction and got the output as I was looking for.Thanks again. Deven

Comment: @user1252544 - glad to help. R definitely has a bit of a learning curve, but it's well worth the effort if you're going to do any significant amount of analysis / modeling / visualization. Lots of good content here on SO to check out as well. Cheers.