# Reshaping in R (...ala SAS PROC Transpose)

Tags: r

I have the following table in R. I want to transpose it. I am new to R and have been using SAS.

So I want to have a replica of proc transpose is SAS. I am giving the output also in which format I want it.

```
C_number<-c(1:20)
REG<-letters[1:20]
Market<-c(21:40)
DF<-data.frame(C_number,REG,Market)
n <- nrow(DF)
DF$A_count <- sample(100, n, replace=TRUE) 
DF$B_count <- sample(100, n, replace=TRUE)
```

the OUTPUT should be:

```
C_number          REG       Market      Name of former variable          Mem_count1
1                  A        21          A_count                           5
1                  A        21          B_count                           80
2                  B        22          A_count                           36
2                  B        22          B_count                           56
3                  C        23          A_count                           77
3                  C        23          B_count                           26
```

**So, the basic idea behind the transpose is to convert two columns A_count & B_count into one named as "name of former variable" and creating a new column mem_count1 which will give the respective values.**

Its not exactly a transpose but kind of similar. I have no clue how to do this. Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Although asked differently; this is pretty close to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586636/matrix-stacking-with-column-name-in-r.  Also, as the original post states, not exactly a transpose, could we make up a better term since transpose has a pretty definite meaning?  Perhaps merge, stack, reshape, or transforming columns in R?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `reshape2` (or `reshape` package) for that and specially the `melt` function.
Using a dataset like yours (not the same because of different random seeds) we can something like this:

```
require(reshape2)
DF_result <- melt(DF,  measure.vars = c("A_count", "B_count"))
head(DF_result)


##   C_number REG Market variable value
## 1        1   a     21  A_count    49
## 2        2   b     22  A_count    99
## 3        3   c     23  A_count    19
## 4        4   d     24  A_count    43
## 5        5   e     25  A_count    53
## 6        6   f     26  A_count    50
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it with the base function `reshape`:

```
reshape(DF,
        direction="long",
        idvar=1:3, varying=c("A_count","B_count"), # the constant and varying columns
        times=c("A_count","B_count"),     # sets the values for new 'source' column
        v.names="Name_of_former_variable" ) # the header for the 'source' column

                C_number REG Market    time Counts
1.a.21.A_count         1   a     21 A_count     14
2.b.22.A_count         2   b     22 A_count     18
3.c.23.A_count         3   c     23 A_count     49
4.d.24.A_count         4   d     24 A_count     64
5.e.25.A_count         5   e     25 A_count     99
6.f.26.A_count         6   f     26 A_count     10
7.g.27.A_count         7   g     27 A_count     70
8.h.28.A_count         8   h     28 A_count      1
snipped output
```